# Where does runtimeconfig.json take includedFrameworks's version setting from?

Tags: .net-core, dotnet-cli, dotnet-sdk, dotnet-publish, dotnet-build

I am investigating why my deployed dotnet core worker service app's `runtimeconfig.json`'s `includedFrameworks`'s version setting has changed from 3.1.31 to 3.1.32 for both
`Microsoft.NETCore.App` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` entries.

What are the factors that will automatically change the `version` setting ?

1. SDK version installed during publishing ?
2. Csproj settings ?

These did not change.

I have been looking in dotnet's docs [here](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/main/documentation/specs/runtime-configuration-file.md) and [here](https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/12/21/netcore-primitives/), but could not yet find an answer.